# SQL - Adding user defined variables to table (mysql)?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, cursor

So I have this code thats part of a stored procedure:

```
SET @MID = 0;
SET @MX = 0;
SET @MY = 0;
SET @MT = 0;
SET @CSTAMP = '2014-6-06 08:03:19';



  SELECT @MID=m.ID, @MX=m.x , @MY=m.y , @MT=m.timestamp FROM movement m
  WHERE m.ID = cSID 
  AND m.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(T.timestamp) 
                     FROM (SELECT mm.timestamp FROM movement mm WHERE mm.ID = cSID AND mm.timestamp <= @CSTAMP)AS T);



INSERT INTO DBTable(`ctimestamp`,`ID`,`x`,`y`,`mtimestamp`) 
VALUES(ctstamp,@MID,@MX,@MY,@MT);
```

Basically, it creates some user-defined variables, assigns them values in the query, and tries to insert them into a table called `DBTable` with columns `ctimestamp`,`ID`,`x`,`y`,`mtimestamp`. The problem is that when I saw the `DBTable` after the query,the columns `ID`,`x`,`y`,and `mtimestamp` were all empty(just 0's), and only the `ctimestamp` got populated with the values from cursor variable `ctstamp`.

I don't know whats wrong here... am I inserting into a table wrong? Can I not insert variables like `@variable_name` this way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

**EDIT**

I just had a thought, since user-defined variables are session-specific, does that mean that I cannot exit out my client and turn off the computer and just let the DB server run the rest of the query? Sorry if that seems like a dumb question, but I'm very new to stored procedures & SQL.

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data.  Specfically, select all your variables prior to your insert query.  If they are all null, look at your select query and see how many rows it returns.

Comment: Yeah I'd check to see if cSID is actually returning anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a SELECT statement, assignment to user defined variables use the (pascal-like) assignment operator (**`:=`**) rather than just an equals sign.

For example, this performs an assignment of the value `'foo'` to the user defined variable:

```
  SELECT @var := 'foo'
              ^
```

That is much different than this:

```
  SELECT @var = 'foo'
              ^
```

This does *not* perform an assignment; it's evaluated as a boolean expression, the result of the equality comparison returns returns 0, 1 or NULL.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

There's no need for all those user-defined variables. You can accomplish the same result more efficiently (with fewer SQL statements)

Assuming `cSID` is a procedure variable, you could accomplish an equivalent result with just:

```
  SET @CSTAMP = '2014-6-06 08:03:19';

  INSERT INTO DBTable(`ctimestamp`,`ID`,`x`,`y`,`mtimestamp`) 
  SELECT t.ctimestamp, m.ID, m.x, m.y, m.timestamp AS mtimestamp
    FROM movement m
    JOIN ( SELECT @CSTAMP + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS ctimestamp
                , MAX(mm.timestamp) AS max_mm_timestamp
             FROM movement mm
            WHERE mm.ID = cSID
              AND mm.timestamp <= @CSTAMP + INTERVAL 0 DAY
         ) t
      ON m.ID = cSID
     AND m.timestamp = t.max_mm_timestamp
   ORDER BY 3,4
   LIMIT 1
```

(The user-defined variable @CSTAMP could be replaced with a procedure variable.

```
  DECLARE v_cstamp DATETIME DEFAULT '2014-06-06 08:03:19';
```

Then replace the reference to to `@CSTAMP` with a reference to the procedure variable... `v_cstamp`.

Comment: Ohhh I see. So basically for example, the `@MID=m.ID` was a meaningless statement in regards to what I want to do

Comment: Yes,  The SELECT is valid in that `SELECT 'a'='b'` is a valid statement. But that's not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off if you use normal variables in your stored procedure. The session variables do not have a datatype and may change during procedure execution if you happen to call other procedures which use the same session variables.

```
DECLARE v_mid int;
DECLARE v_mx int;
DECLARE v_my int;
DECLARE v_mt int;
DECLARE v_time datetime;

SELECT m.ID, m.x, m.y, m.timestamp INTO v_mid, v_mx, v_my, v_mt, v_time
FROM movement m
WHERE m.ID = cSID 
AND m.timestamp = (
    SELECT MAX(mm.timestamp) 
    FROM movement mm 
    WHERE mm.ID = cSID AND mm.timestamp <= v_time
);


INSERT INTO DBTable(`ctimestamp`,`ID`,`x`,`y`,`mtimestamp`) 
VALUES(v_time,v_mid,v_mx,v_my,v_mt);
```

Comment: I see...thanks, I'll keep that in mind. So in doing it this way, there's no change, except the type of variable right? I'm not calling any other procedures that use any of the `@var_name`'s so this can't be my error right? In any case, I'll change it and see how it goes

Comment: See the SELECT INTO syntax instead of the var = column syntax. The var = column syntax is used by SQL Server / Sybase. MySQL uses the SELECT INTO syntax.

Comment: An equivalent could be accomplished in a single `INSERT ... SELECT` statement, rather than separate `SELECT` and `INSERT` statements, eliminating the need for storing the values in procedure variables.

Comment: Yes, INSERT ... SELECT is a better solution in this case. Was just answering to the question how variables can be used inside a procedure.